# c# converting datetime in a different culture

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert a german DateTime value into a french DateTime object.

The value of my item called "_dateFacture" is "08.07.2015 17:23:01"

```
var stringdate = _dateFacture.ToString(new CultureInfo("fr-FR")); //d2 = "08/07/2015 17:23:01"
var testfinal = DateTime.Parse(stringdate, new CultureInfo("fr-FR")); // testfinal = "08.07.2015 17:23:01"
```

How is it possible for the object testfinal to get a value like that ?

Comment: `DateTime`s don't have any specific culture associated with them. When you stringify them, you *do* use culture information to format the string. `testfinal` is just a `DateTime` so likely what you're seeing is the result of stringifying it in your default culture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you saw is just a representation issue. They are the same `DateTime` values.

`DateTime` doesn't have *any* implicit format. And it doesn't have *any* `IFormatProvider`. It just a date and time values. Format is only a subject when you try to get it's *textual* representation.

I strongly suspect you see this in your debugger or something;

[image]

Your `stringdate` is a `string`, but your `testfinal` is a `DateTime`. If you wanna save your datetime values in your database, don't save their string representations. Put your datetime values directly to your parameterized queries.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: So you mean that if I save in database a value with "." or "/", there will be the same values in the table ?

Comment: @user2621595 Don't save your `DateTime` values with their string representations. Insert them with in a parameterized queries directly. And database keep them as a binary. A `DateTime` itself doesn't have _any_ `.` or `/`.

Answer (score 2):

If you had declared the datatype with each variable, instead of using var, it would have been easier to spot.

```
  string stringdate = _dateFacture.ToString(new CultureInfo("fr-FR")); 

  DateTime testfinal = DateTime.Parse(stringdate, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

testfinal is a DateTime, not a string.

When you look at it in a debugger or view, testfinal is converted to a string using DateTime.ToString() which uses the current culture (which presumably displays dates with a dot).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store testfinal as a datetime, you just need to make sure your var is in fact a DateTime.

```
DateTime testfinal = DateTime.Parse(stringdate, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

To show it you can use a format in the ToString function:

```
string formattedDate = testfinal.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
//now your formattedDate  will be "08.07.2015 17:23:01"
```